# How to make a suction sound?

Tags: design, ideas, cloud

Imagnine you are being sucked into a TV, what sound would it make?

Or what if you had just teleported into a zone and somebody asked you about this sound design technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waves dashing themselves against rocks, reversed, pitched down, slowed to half and gradually sped up to double as you get closer to the screen.

Comment: Actually make that sped up to double and slowed down to half as you get closer. 

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a normal kind of 'sucking' sound like a reversed plunger or something similar, and add some kind of electronic sound as well, maybe an automated low-pass filter sweep on a White Noise sample?

Cheers

Comment: Seems a little bit too simple though.  I'm thinking general principles as well.  Thanks for shedding some light though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mouth!  Actually any kind of reverse can be a suction.  After you reverse, add reverb or fx delay and reverse again!